# Did they really make ice cream/cake in shape of "Raising the Flag on Iwo Jima" as shown in the movie?

Tags: historical-accuracy, flags-of-our-fathers

In Flags of our Fathers, after the completion of the war, the soldiers get an invitation for celebrations.

In one scene the soldiers get an ice cream cake in the shape of "[Raising the Flag on Iwo Jima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_the_Flag_on_Iwo_Jima)" and the pantry man poured strawberry juice on it in resemblance of blood to us (the audience).

[image]

Did they really make an ice cream cake in the shape of "Raising the Flag on Iwo Jima" as shown in the movie?

Comment: Good question. I think this was probably just something created by Eastwood for the movie but it's not inconceivable.